# Python 3 Limit count of active threads (finished threads do not quit)

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, class, python-3.6

I want to limit the number of active threads. What i have seen is, that a finished thread stays alive and does not exit itself, so the number of active threads keep growing until an error occours.

The following code starts only 8 threads at a time but they stay alive even when they finished. So the number keeps growing:

```
class ThreadEx(threading.Thread):
    __thread_limiter = None
    __max_threads = 2

    @classmethod
    def max_threads(cls, thread_max):
        ThreadEx.__max_threads = thread_max
        ThreadEx.__thread_limiter = threading.BoundedSemaphore(value=ThreadEx.__max_threads)

    def __init__(self, target=None, args:tuple=()):
        super().__init__(target=target, args=args)
        if not ThreadEx.__thread_limiter:
            ThreadEx.__thread_limiter = threading.BoundedSemaphore(value=ThreadEx.__max_threads)

    def run(self):
        ThreadEx.__thread_limiter.acquire()
        try:
            #success = self._target(*self._args)
            #if success: return True
            super().run()
        except:
            pass
        finally:
            ThreadEx.__thread_limiter.release()


def call_me(test1, test2):
    print(test1 + test2)
    time.sleep(1)


ThreadEx.max_threads(8)

for i in range(0, 99):
    t = ThreadEx(target=call_me, args=("Thread count: ", str(threading.active_count())))
    t.start()
```

Due to the for loop, the number of threads keep growing to 99.
I know that a thread has done its work because *call_me* has been executed and *threading.active_count()* was printed.

Does somebody know how i make sure, a finished thread does not stay alive?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python , you might find this useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a silly answer but to me it looks you are trying to reinvent `ThreadPool`.

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from time import sleep

p = ThreadPool(8)

def call_me(test1):
    print(test1)
    sleep(1)

for i in range(0, 99):
    p.apply_async(call_me, args=(i,))

p.close()
p.join()
```

This will ensure only 8 concurrent threads are running your function at any point of time. And if you want a bit more performance, you can import `Pool` from multiprocessing and use that. The interface is exactly the same but your pool will now be subprocesses instead of threads, which usually gives a performance boost as GIL does not come in the way.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the class according to the help of Hannu.

I post it for reference, maybe it's useful for others that come across this post:

```
import threading
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import time

    class MultiThread():
    __thread_pool = None

    @classmethod
    def begin(cls, max_threads):
        MultiThread.__thread_pool = ThreadPool(max_threads)

    @classmethod
    def end(cls):
        MultiThread.__thread_pool.close()
        MultiThread.__thread_pool.join()

    def __init__(self, target=None, args:tuple=()):
        self.__target = target
        self.__args = args

    def run(self):
        try:
            result = MultiThread.__thread_pool.apply_async(self.__target, args=self.__args)
            return result.get()
        except:
            pass


def call_me(test1, test2):
    print(test1 + test2)
    time.sleep(1)
    return 0


MultiThread.begin(8)
for i in range(0, 99):
    t = MultiThread(target=call_me, args=("Thread count: ", str(threading.active_count())))
    t.run()
MultiThread.end()
```

The maximum of threads is 8 at any given time determined by the method *begin*. 
And also the method *run* returns the result of your passed function if it returns something.

Hope that helps.